# Why this Userscripts doesn't work for my site

Tags: javascript, automation, userscripts

My friends have a site for the blind. They build the site to help the visual impaired community to download some audio movies to listen on the go. I want to help them build an IMDB movie list to list all of that titles.

I was using Microsoft Excel and some web crawling program to gather up the data then building a CSV file and import it into the IMDB website on a movie list of my account. It happened that there are some Userscripts wrote for Google Chrome to work the import. I can make a CSV text file contains the IMDB movie IDs and the description of films in comma separated pairs and then use the scripts to load the file then do importing thing.

But there was problem. When I try to run the script to do the work, it run for some lines of the file and stopped at the middle xxx and then nothing have happens. I have little computer knowledge though. I have read a tutorial of JavaScript for a some days so that I can understand the structure of it then try to see into the code to see what's happening but still I don't understand why the code doesn't do its work as I want.

The code is not belongs to me. It's created by some programmer on the web  and when I get to the code, it didn't work on the format of the file. I was able to tweak some variables to make the thing run but still it stopped at the middle of the thing xxx. How can I find out what's wrong?

Here is the code of the scripts.

```
    // ==UserScript==
// @name         IMDB List Importer
// @namespace    Neinei0k_imdb
// @include      https://www.imdb.com/list/*
// @include      http://*imdb.com/list/*/edit
// @include      http://*imdb.com/list/*/edit?*
// @include      https://*imdb.com/list/*/edit
// @include      https://*imdb.com/list/*/edit?*
// @include      *
// @version  7.0
// @grant        GM.xmlHttpRequest
// @description  Import list of titles or people in the imdb list
// ==/UserScript==

var o = {

init: function(e) {
    this.etext = e.querySelector('textarea');
    this.efile = e.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
    this.eready = e.children[10]; // DOM element with messages for the user.
    var checkboxes = e.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    this.source = checkboxes[0];
    this.csv = checkboxes[1];
    this.unique = checkboxes[2];

  var hidden_element = document.querySelector('#main > input'); // Unknown hidden element. Data needs to be send with all requests.
  if (hidden_element == null) {
    this.log('e','Hidden element not found');
  } else {
    this.hidden_data = hidden_element.id + "=" + hidden_element.value;
  }
},

run: function(event) {
    this.text = this.etext.value;
    if (this.source.checked) { // read data from file
        var file = this.efile.files[0];
        if (file !== undefined) {
            this.log("i","Reading file " + file.name);
            var r = new FileReader();
            r.onload = this.file_onload.bind(this);
            r.readAsText(file);
        } else {
            this.log("e","File is undefined");
        }
    } else { // read data from input element
        this.add_list(this.create_list());
    }
},

file_onload: function(e) {
    if (e.target.error === null) {
        this.text = e.target.result;
        this.add_list(this.create_list());
    } else {
        this.log("e","File reading error: " + e.target.error);
    }
},

log: function(level,msg) {
    var l = "";
  switch (level) {
    case 'i': l = "Info: "; break;
    case 'w': l = "Warning: "; break;
    case 'e': l = "Error: "; break;
  }
    if (l.length !== 0) {
        console.log("IMDB List Importer: " + l + msg);
    }
    if (level == "n" || level == "e") {
        this.eready.innerText = msg;
    }
},

create_list: function() {
    var re;
    // Find type of the list
    /*if (document.querySelector('[data-type="Characters"]') !== null) {
        this.log("i", "List type: characters");
        re = "ch";
    } else*/
  if (document.querySelector('[data-type="People"]') !== null) {
        this.log("i", "List type: people");
        re = "nm";
    } else if (document.querySelector('[data-type="Titles"]') !== null) {
        this.log("i", "List type: titles");
        re = "tt";
    } else {
        this.log("e","Could not determine type of the list");
        return [];
    }
    re += "[0-9]{5,10}";

    if (this.csv.checked) {
        return this.read_csv(re);
    } else {
        re = new RegExp(re);
        var list = [];
        var e;
        var text = this.text;
        while ((e = re.exec(text)) !== null) {
            var flag = '';
            if (this.unique.checked) flag = 'g';
            text = text.replace(new RegExp(e[0], flag), '');
            list.push({const: e[0], description: ""});
        }
        return list;
    }
},

read_csv: function(re) {
    re = new RegExp("^" + re + "$");
    var list = [];

  // Parse csv
  var text = this.text.split('\r\n'); // Separate by lines
  this.text = null; // Variable may have lots of data which is no longer needed
  var parsed_text = [];
  for (var i in text) { // For each line
    if (text[i].trim().length === 0) { // Ignore empty lines including lines with only white space characters
      continue;
    }
    var state = 0; // 0 - outside of double quotes (comma character is the separator), 1 - inside double quotes (comma character is part of a field)
    var parsed_line = [""];
    for (var j in text[i]) {
      if (state == 0 && text[i][j] == ',') {
        parsed_line.push("");
      } else if (text[i][j] == '"') {
        state = (state + 1) % 2;
      } else {
        parsed_line[parsed_line.length-1] += text[i][j];
      }
    }
    parsed_text.push(parsed_line);
  }
  text = parsed_text;

  // console.log(text); // print parsed data

    // Find const and description field numbers.
    try {
    if (text.length < 2) { // There must be at least 2 rows in the data
        throw "No data";
    }
        var fl = text[0];
        var fll = fl.length;
        var const_field = fl.indexOf('const');
        if (const_field === -1) {
      const_field = fl.indexOf('Const');
      if (const_field === -1) {
        throw "Field 'const' not found.";
      }
    }
    } catch (err) {
        this.log("e","Input line 1: " + err);
        return [];
    }
  var desc_field = fl.indexOf('description');
        if (desc_field === -1) {
      desc_field = fl.indexOf('Description');
    }

    this.log("i","Found csv file fields const(" + const_field +
                 ") and description(" + desc_field + ")");
    text.shift();

    // Add elements to the list
    for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (text[i].length === 0)
            continue;

        try {
            fl = text[i];
            if (fll !== fl.length) throw "Invalid number of fields.";
            if (re.exec(fl[const_field]) === null) throw "Invalid 'const' field.";
        } catch (err) {
            this.log("e","Input line " + (i+2) + ": " + err);
            return [];
        }
        if (this.unique.checked) {
            var exists = list.findIndex(function(v){
                return v.const === fl[const_field];
            });
            if (exists !== -1) continue;
        }
        list.push({const: fl[const_field],description: (desc_field == -1 ? "" : fl[desc_field])});
    }

  // console.log(list); // Print final list

    return list;
},

add_list: function(list) {
    if (list.length === 0)
        return;

    var msg = "Elements to add: ";
    for (var i in list)
        msg += list[i].const + ",";
    this.log("i",msg);

    var l = {};
    l.list = list;
    l.ready = 0;
    l.list_id = /ls[0-9]{1,}/.exec(location.href)[0];

    this.sendNext(l);
},

sendNext: function(l) {
    this.log("i",'Add element ' + l.ready + ': ' + l.list[l.ready].const);
    this.send_request(this.check_item, l, 'https://www.imdb.com/list/' + l.list_id + '/' + l.list[l.ready].const + '/add', this.hidden_data);
},

send_request: function(f,l,u,d) {
  GM.xmlHttpRequest({
    method: "POST",
    url: u,
    data: d,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    onreadystatechange: f.bind(this,l)
  });
    /*var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.onreadystatechange = f.bind(this,l);
    x.open('POST', u, true);
    x.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',
      'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    x.send(d);*/
},

check_item: function(l, e) {
    this.log("i","Add element(" + l.list[l.ready].const +
                 ") request: readyState(" + e.readyState +
                 "), status(" + e.status + ")");
    if (e.readyState == 4 && e.status == 200) {
        if (l.list[l.ready].description.length !== 0) {
            this.send_request(this.check_item_desc, l, 'https://www.imdb.com/list/' + l.list_id + '/edit/itemdescription',
                              'newDescription=' + l.list[l.ready].description +
                              '&listItem=' + JSON.parse(e.responseText).list_item_id + '&' + this.hidden_data);
        } else {
            this.showReady(l);
        }
    }
},

check_item_desc: function(l,e) {
    this.log("i","Add element(" + l.list[l.ready].const +
                 ") description request: readyState(" + e.readyState +
                 "), status(" + e.status + ")");
    if (e.readyState == 4 && e.status == 200) {
        this.showReady(l);
    }
},

showReady: function(l) {
    l.ready += 1;
    this.log("n",'Ready ' + l.ready + ' of ' + l.list.length + '.');
    if (l.ready == l.list.length) {
        alert("The job is done. You can now reload the page to see result!");
    } else {
        this.sendNext(l);
    }
},

change: function(e) {
    var s = e.target.checked;
    this.etext.disabled = s;
    this.efile.disabled = !s;
},

};

var c = window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob; // Check support of File API
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('class', 'search-bar');
div.style.height = "initial"
var s = '<textarea style="background-color: white; width: 100%; height: 100px; overflow: initial"></textarea><br>';
if (c) {
    s += '<input type="file" disabled><br>';
    s += '<label>';
    s += '<input type="checkbox" style="width: initial;">';
    s += '<span style="font-weight: normal;">';
    s += 'Import from file (otherwise import from text)';
    s += '</span>';
    s += '</label><br>';
} else {
    s += '<span style="font-weight: normal;">';
    s += 'Looks like your browser does not support File API for reading local files.';
    s += '</span><br>';
}
s += '<label>';
s += '<input type="checkbox" checked style="width: initial;">';
s += '<span style="font-weight: normal;">Data from .csv file</span>';
s += '</label><br>';
s += '<label>';
s += '<input type="checkbox" style="width: initial;">';
s += '<span style="font-weight: normal;">Add only unique elements</span>';
s += '</label><br>';
s += '<div>Set-up parameters. Insert text or choose file. Press \'Import List\' button.</div>';
s += '<button class="btn">Import List</button>';
div.innerHTML = s;

o.init(div);
div.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',o.run.bind(o),false);
if (c) {
    o.source.addEventListener('change',o.change.bind(o),false);
}

var list_edit = document.querySelector('.lister-search');
list_edit.appendChild(div);
```

And here is the link to the data file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zfSutdmt2SvDwgrrqOpnf0T8b0Ko8IgV/view?usp=drivesdk

The text in the data file look like these.

```
"Const","Description",\r\n
"tt0472033","LINK(S) ON AUDIOVAULT:\n
9 (2009):\n
http://audiovault.net/download/2787",\r\n
"tt0478087","LINK(S) ON AUDIOVAULT:\n
21 (2008):\n
http://audiovault.net/download/2746",\r\n
"tt0285331","LINK(S) ON AUDIOVAULT:\n
24 - Season 2 (2002):\n
http://audiovault.net/download/5\n
24 - Season 3 (2003):\n
http://audiovault.net/download/8920\n
24 - Season 4 (2005):\n
http://audiovault.net/download/7\n
24 - Season 5 (2006):\n
http://audiovault.net/download/8\n
24 - Season 6 (2008):\n
http://audiovault.net/download/9\n
24 - Season 7 (2009):\n
http://audiovault.net/download/10\n
24 - Season 8 (2010):\n
http://audiovault.net/download/11\n
24 Season 1 (not described):\n
http://audiovault.net/download/8919",\r\n
"tt0453562","LINK(S) ON AUDIOVAULT:\n
42 (2013):\n
http://audiovault.net/download/2768",\r\n
"tt0120577","LINK(S) ON AUDIOVAULT:\n
54 (1998):\n
http://audiovault.net/download/2776",\r\n
"tt0416449","LINK(S) ON AUDIOVAULT:\n
300 (2006):\n
http://audiovault.net/download/2761",
```

Each comma separated value pair is contained in a line, the script processes thing this way. In each value of the value pair, text might contain line breaks. It mean maybe many lines of text in a value. I end a line of value pair in [carriage return][line feed] characters and in the code above I mark it with a "\r\n". This couple of characters is not visible in notepad though. And if in a value text contain many line breaks, I break it with a [line feed] character. In the text above I marked it with a "\n". This character is not visible in Notepad too.

The first few lines of the data are processed well by the script but when it encounters the 9th line it stopped processing. This is the text of the line.

```
"tt4922804","LINK(S) ON AUDIOVAULT:
3% - Season 1 (Portugese Description) (2016):
http://audiovault.net/download/9148
3% - Season 2 (Portugese Description) (2018):
http://audiovault.net/download/9152",
```

When I look into the log file of Google Chrome, it seemed that when it send the request to the server to process the line, the server send back a status 400. The server is sending status 0 for all of the lines before it the 9th line, but when the script send request to process the line, it got status 400. I don't understand very much these the thing though. And so everything stopped.

Here is a piece of log text when the script stopped process the lines.

```
userscript.html?id=05c2d50a-7d60-4131-88b9-ca8f655a1300:74 IMDB List Importer: Info: Add element 7: tt1190080
userscript.html?id=05c2d50a-7d60-4131-88b9-ca8f655a1300:74 IMDB List Importer: Info: Add element(tt1190080) request: readyState(1), status(0)
userscript.html?id=05c2d50a-7d60-4131-88b9-ca8f655a1300:74 IMDB List Importer: Info: Add element(tt1190080) request: readyState(2), status(0)
userscript.html?id=05c2d50a-7d60-4131-88b9-ca8f655a1300:74 IMDB List Importer: Info: Add element(tt1190080) request: readyState(3), status(0)
userscript.html?id=05c2d50a-7d60-4131-88b9-ca8f655a1300:74 IMDB List Importer: Info: Add element(tt1190080) request: readyState(4), status(200)
userscript.html?id=05c2d50a-7d60-4131-88b9-ca8f655a1300:74 IMDB List Importer: Info: Add element(tt1190080) description request: readyState(1), status(0)
userscript.html?id=05c2d50a-7d60-4131-88b9-ca8f655a1300:74 IMDB List Importer: Info: Add element(tt1190080) description request: readyState(2), status(0)
userscript.html?id=05c2d50a-7d60-4131-88b9-ca8f655a1300:74 IMDB List Importer: Info: Add element(tt1190080) description request: readyState(3), status(0)
userscript.html?id=05c2d50a-7d60-4131-88b9-ca8f655a1300:74 IMDB List Importer: Info: Add element(tt1190080) description request: readyState(4), status(200)
userscript.html?id=05c2d50a-7d60-4131-88b9-ca8f655a1300:74 IMDB List Importer: Info: Add element 8: tt4922804
userscript.html?id=05c2d50a-7d60-4131-88b9-ca8f655a1300:74 IMDB List Importer: Info: Add element(tt4922804) request: readyState(1), status(0)
userscript.html?id=05c2d50a-7d60-4131-88b9-ca8f655a1300:74 IMDB List Importer: Info: Add element(tt4922804) request: readyState(2), status(0)
userscript.html?id=05c2d50a-7d60-4131-88b9-ca8f655a1300:74 IMDB List Importer: Info: Add element(tt4922804) request: readyState(3), status(0)
userscript.html?id=05c2d50a-7d60-4131-88b9-ca8f655a1300:74 IMDB List Importer: Info: Add element(tt4922804) request: readyState(4), status(200)
userscript.html?id=05c2d50a-7d60-4131-88b9-ca8f655a1300:74 IMDB List Importer: Info: Add element(tt4922804) description request: readyState(1), status(0)
userscript.html?id=05c2d50a-7d60-4131-88b9-ca8f655a1300:74 IMDB List Importer: Info: Add element(tt4922804) description request: readyState(2), status(0)
userscript.html?id=05c2d50a-7d60-4131-88b9-ca8f655a1300:74 IMDB List Importer: Info: Add element(tt4922804) description request: readyState(3), status(0)
userscript.html?id=05c2d50a-7d60-4131-88b9-ca8f655a1300:74 IMDB List Importer: Info: Add element(tt4922804) description request: readyState(4), status(400)
```

I think there was something not covered in the function send the request to process the line but I don't quite understand the code in them because my understand of the web protocols and JavaScript is quite weak. By the way this is the link to the console log file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pfxz1fEMR9QR8AUmCcQczgfqCy7a66NP/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Please include the code into the question itself, links rot and can become unusable thus making the q&a useless for future users. Not to mention we shouldn't have to go offsite to view the code

Comment: Patrick is quite right that we need to see the code here, on Stack Overflow. However, if all that code is posted here, it would then be "Needs more focus", since no debugging has been done. Could you add some `console.log()` statements to it, and run it again, to see where it stops running?

Comment: @halfer What do you mean by "Needs more focus". And what is the flag icon before the comment for. I have updated my question. Hope to receive some solution. Sorry, this is my first time to use Overflow. I don't quite understand how to use it yet.

Comment: Hi there, I am happy to explain. Stack Overflow is rather different to other sources of help you may have used on the internet. Most other places are like chat rooms or discussion forums where pretty much any question is permitted. Here, we are looking for questions that might be useful to many programmers, far into the future. To that end the community may close some questions that do not fit.

Comment: Questions can be closed for a number of official reasons, and it is the job of community voters to decide what reasons apply (if any). The one I mentioned, "needs more focus", used to be called "too broad". That means what it sounds like - the question is unanswerable because there are too many possible answers. Your question is better after the edit (thank you) but there is still a lot of code for someone to wade through. There are still resources to obtain from an external file locker.

Comment: There are still some areas that lack clarity in my view. What does "stopped at the middle xxx" and "stopped at the middle of the thing xxx" mean? Are the x's a placeholder for something?

Comment: Final note - apologies for the verbosity! - a good rule of thumb is to work out how readers here can replicate the problem. Unfortunately some problems are just not replicable in a question. For example, if a reader would have to go to your friend's website, and install the user script in his/her browser, in order to replicate the problem, then I can't see any way we can reopen it. I appreciate that's frustrating, but when that site changes - and it will over time - the phenomena in your question will no longer be exhibited.

Comment: So, if there is a quick way a JavaScript problem can be shown e.g. a JS Fiddle or a Stack Snippet - then it is probably on-topic. But this appears to _need_ more external resources. However, if it cannot be made to fit here, then you have not wasted your time - you could paste the Markdown into a Reddit question and ask it in a suitable room there.

Comment: Well, my English is not good. It lacks of the vocabulary to describe the problem in a natural way so I put some xxx there for some words and thing that I can't speak it out. And in order to replicate the problem, yes you have to go to imdb.com site, signup an account and create a movie list. Then install Tamper Monkey for Google Chrome and install the script above by pasting its text into Notepad and save as a xxx.user.js file and install it in Tampermonkey.  After that, go to the movie list of your account on IMDB and click on edit. The script should run and you can import the csv file there.

Comment: By the way, if nobody have the  time to help me here, do you know a good website that I can get the help. I don't think Reddit is good because it seems they speak on it about general problems. But I'm not very sure though. I hope to find a good programming website where people help another with codes.

Comment: Maybe there is a Tamper Monkey help forum, where people would be willing to install a tamper script and log into websites. It's not necessarily the case that people here don't have time - it is just that this is not the purpose of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Well, I have posted the question to greasyfork.org but no one answer. I just thought Stack Overflow is about programming and this Userscripts thing is script. Hope someone can help checking the code because I really need it for the job.